# Как доработать document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который удаляет класс gsap-reveal-hero , на мобильных экранах, но проблема в том, что он удаляет класс только на одном элементе.
Как доработать, чтобы было множественное удаление класса на всех элементах, где есть класс gsap-reveal-hero ??

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    document.querySelector('.heading').classList.remove('gsap-reveal-hero');
} else {
    document.querySelector('.heading').classList.add('gsap-reveal-hero');
}
```

});

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Вы можете использовать CSS медиа-запросы для этого

Comment: Почему то при document.querySelectorAll , выдает ошибку в консоли 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: CSS медиа-запросы к сожалению не подходят

Comment: "Почему то при document.querySelectorAll , выдает ошибку в консоли Uncaught TypeError" -- потому что возвращает [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList), а не элемент.

Comment: @АндрейКурусь Что-то здесь не так... `HTMLDocument` - это `document`, у него нет метода `add`, чего вы ещё ожидали? Возможно вы неправильно написали `addEventListener`?

Comment: @Simon была ошибка с `classList`, а не `add` если это был бы `NodeList`. Сами проверьте: `document.querySelectorAll('div').classList.add('here will be error')`

Comment: @ΝNL993 Вы правы, я не дочитал текст ошибки до конца.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение через `querySelectorAll` на событии `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.heading'))
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('gsap-reveal-hero');
    }) 
  } else {
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add('gsap-reveal-hero');
    }) 
  }
})
```

```css
.gsap-reveal-hero{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 1</h2>
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 2</h2>
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 3</h2>
```

В данном случае я бы все же обратил внимание на решение через медиа запросы, а именно `window.matchMedia` и событие `change`, это решение гибче — подхватывает изменения размеров (откройте снипет на всю страницу и меняйте размеры окна):

```js
const mediaQuery = "screen and (max-width: 757px)"
const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.heading'))

const updateStyles = () => {
  const isMax757 = matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches   
  matchMedia(mediaQuery).addEventListener("change", updateStyles, 
   { 
     once: true 
     /* эта опция делает автоматическую отписку 
     от события после срабатывания — нет утечки памяти */
   })
  if (isMax757){
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.remove('gsap-reveal-hero');
    }) 
  } else {
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add('gsap-reveal-hero');
    }) 
  }
}

updateStyles(); // инициализация
```

```css
.gsap-reveal-hero{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 1</h2>
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 2</h2>
<h2 class='heading gsap-reveal-hero'>header 3</h2>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваше первое решение больше подходит